# Crashed: com.apple.NSURLSession-delegate - EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: swift, crashlytics, nsurlsession, stack-trace

I'm seeing this crash from many users in Google's Crashlytics. I posted the stack trace below, but keep in mind that this is happening on many other URL Requests. None of my URL Request functions have been modified within the last few months so I'm wondering if this is an Apple bug with a new iOS version? If someone can break down the stack trace for me and explain if it's an Apple bug or something I can fix, that would be great.

```
Crashed: com.apple.NSURLSession-delegate
0  r6stats                        0x100b29750 closure #1 in UbiApi.GetServerToken(account:) + 28 (UbiApi.swift:28)
1  r6stats                        0x100b282a8 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed Data?, @guaranteed NSURLResponse?, @guaranteed Error?) -> () + 4343775912 (<compiler-generated>:4343775912)
2  CFNetwork                      0x1919f63dc CFNetServiceBrowserSearchForServices + 79304
3  CFNetwork                      0x191a08768 _CFHTTPMessageSetResponseProxyURL + 9196
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x190fbda84 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x190fbf81c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x190fc7004 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 620
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x190fc7c34 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 456
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x190fd24bc _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 764
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1dcf367a4 _pthread_wqthread + 276
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1dcf3d74c start_wqthread + 8
```

```swift
func GetServerToken(account: Int) {
    guard let url = URL(string: ApiHeaders.Tokens().url + String(account)) else { print("Invalid URL"); return }
        
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
        
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, res, err) in
        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(self.dateFormatter)
                
            let json = try decoder.decode(LoginResponse.self, from: data)
                
            let expirationDate : Date = json.expiration!
            let token = "Ubi_v1 t=" + json.ticket!
            let sessionId = json.sessionId
                
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(expirationDate, forKey: "r6_token_expiration_\(account)")
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(token, forKey: "r6_token_\(account)")
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(sessionId, forKey: "r6_token_sessionId_\(account)")
                
            UbiApi.accountsNeeded -= 1 // This is declared on line 28
            self.CheckIfTokensAreDone()
        }
        catch {}
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: Why don't you debug it with an actual device for yourself at first?

Comment: Please show your real code.

Comment: @El Tomato I cannot reproduce it myself. I'm only seeing this crash happen from my users on Crashlytics.

Comment: In how many other places, are you using `URLSession.shared`?

Comment: What's line 28 and around?

Comment: @matt My code is at the bottom. The only thing I took out was a do, try, catch for a JSON Decoder which seems irrelevant to this issue.

Comment: @ElTomato When this is ran, there are 59 other URLSessions being ran at the same time. This hasn't changed though, and was never an issue until recently.

Comment: @Larme A static variable near the top of my class. It is an Int that begins at 60, and every time this function is called (60 times asynchronously), it decreases by 1. Is it possible that the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is coming from too many functions trying to modify the same variable simultaneously?

Comment: If you knew the missing code was irrelevant you wouldn't be asking the question. Your code simply cannot be `guard let data = data else { return }` and no more; no one would write that and stop. You must try to dispose of the data somehow, and I suspect that the problem lies there. Please do as I asked and show your real code.

Comment: Yes, definitely the issue. Please be aware that the crashcode says it crashed at line 28 with `(UbiApi.swift:28)`, not showing that part is fine, you can obfuscate your code and keep it private, but at least give pseudo code or sample renamed. That's a thread issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole last part of your code is thread-unsafe:

```
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(expirationDate, forKey: "r6_token_expiration_\(account)")
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(token, forKey: "r6_token_\(account)")
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(sessionId, forKey: "r6_token_sessionId_\(account)")
            
    UbiApi.accountsNeeded -= 1 // This is declared on line 28
    self.CheckIfTokensAreDone()
```

Serialize it to a safe thread:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(expirationDate, forKey: "r6_token_expiration_\(account)")
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(token, forKey: "r6_token_\(account)")
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(sessionId, forKey: "r6_token_sessionId_\(account)")
            
    UbiApi.accountsNeeded -= 1 // This is declared on line 28
    self.CheckIfTokensAreDone()
}
```